# Find the probability of not owning $x$ or $y$ or both

Tags: probability

Bit confused as to how to work this out.
If the probability of $x$ is $0.35$
and the probability of $y$ is $0.6$
and the probability of $x$ and $y$ is $0.26$

How do I go working out the probability of not owning $x$ or $y$ or both?

Comment: Well, there are only four possibilities:  either you own neither, both, $x$ but not $y$, or $y$ but not $x$.  These are mutually exclusive and exhaustive so the sum of their probabilities is $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's note the following Venn Diagram

[image]

Where I exposed the data in %. As you can see,

- the probabilty to be "out of X, say out of the red", is $34+31=65=100-35=65\%$
- the probabilty to be "out of Y, say out of the blue", is $31+9=40=100-60=40\%$
- the probability to be out of both circles, is $31\%$